# Is AngularJS Filter dys'Functional'?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular, and was curious why the difference in syntax:

```
$log.info("Hi");
```

So `info` is a function of `$log` and take a parameter string.

but...

```
$filter('uppercase')('Hi');
```

Why does "Hi" outside the function?

Why not `$filter('uppercase','HI')`

Whats happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `$filter` is a factory method. `$filter('uppercase')` creates the `uppercase` filter, which in turn is a method. Without assigning the created method to a variable you are calling the method in place.

It's more or less a shortcut for writing

```
var uppercaseFilter = $filter('uppercase');
var filteredString = uppercaseFilter(originalString);
```